# RabbitMQ : block duplicate message that are already in the queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a way for me to prevent having duplicate messages in a queue? But as soon as a message has been consumed, the exact same message should be allowed again in the queue.

The standard duplicate message plugin for RabbitMQ does something different unfortunately. It just blocks duplicate messages from entering in the queue for a certain time. It does not actually CHECK if message is already in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RabbitMQ plugin [queue-level deduplication](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication#queue-level-deduplication) does what you need. It prevents messages to be published within the queue if there is already one with the same header within.

Check the list of supported queues as it does not support all the queue types.

Comment: But why are there duplicates in the first place? I have queues I subscribe to and there are a lot of duplicates upon connection.